# PHP: How to use this code on different page

Tags: php

I'd like to use the code below for multiple pages. I tried putting the `$listloadpage` in an `array("page-1", "page-2")` but `stristr()` doesn't work that way.

```
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$listloadpage = "page-1";
if(stristr($currentpage, $listingloadpage) !== false)
{
    $database->query('SELECT id, name FROM table_1 ORDER BY name', array());
    $results = $database->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

I'd rather not have to repeat the code above for "page-2".

URL would look like `http://www.domain.com/index.php?action=page-1`

**EDIT:** Thanks to Dagon I got it to work...

```
$listloadpage = array("page-1", "page-2");
if(in_array($_GET['action'], $listingloadpage) !== false)
{
    // Display content
}
```

Comment: use in_array() rather than stristr()

Comment: @Dagon It's not displaying the content on the pages. `if(in_array(array("page-1", "page-2"), array($currentpage), true) !== false)`.

Comment: thats backwards, string you are searching for then array

Comment: Second argument MUST be an array according to the docs. http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: `if(in_array($currentpage, array("page-1", "page-2"), true) !== false)`

Comment: Nope. But I think I know why. `stristr()` is looking for any match. `in_array()` is looking for an exact match. So I'd have to change it to `if(in_array($currentpage, array("index.php?action=page-1", "index.php?action=page-2")`

Comment: i was fixing your syntax, i assumed you knew what the variables where. you could just use $_GET['action']

Comment: @Dagon Ah, thanks. `if(in_array($_GET['action'], array("page-1", "page-2")) !== false)
` works

Answer (score 1):

`strstr()` and other string related functions are for **strings**, not **arrays**. if you want to check if given value is in array, use `in_array()` instead. See the docs: https://www.php.net/in_array

In general I recommend you go thru list of [all available array related functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) to find out what PHP already offrs.

Comment: fell free to turn my comment in to an answerer ;)

Comment: Didn't see your comment while posting my answer.

Comment: `in_array()` won't work because `$listloadpage` is only part of the URL. I've edited my OP to show what `$currentpage` would look like. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Draven it will, just use $_GET['action']

Answer (score 0):

You can use include method (http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), or look for "pretty url" feature of php